# Is tarpc hard limited to 64 RPCs per connection?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-tarpc

So I was playing around with the tarpc example library and wanted to see the limit of how many RPC calls the channel can support. I used [this example from GitHub](https://github.com/google/tarpc/tree/master/example-service).

I modified it slightly to print results and the server works as expected every time you run a new client and sends a message back to the client to be displayed.

I then decided to change the client to keep sending RPCs instead of sending one and stopping.

I changed this code:

```
let hello = async move {
    // Send the request twice, just to be safe! ;)
    tokio::select! {
        hello1 = client.hello(context::current(), format!("{}1", flags.name)) => { hello1 }
        hello2 = client.hello(context::current(), format!("{}2", flags.name)) => { hello2 }
    }
}
.instrument(tracing::info_span!("Two Hellos"))
.await;

match hello {
    Ok(hello) => tracing::info!("{hello:?}"),
    Err(e) => tracing::warn!("{:?}", anyhow::Error::from(e)),
}
```

Into this:

```
let mut N:i32 = 0;
loop{
    N += 1; 
    println!("Call number {}", N); 
    
    let result = async {
        tokio::select! { client.hello(context::current(), format!("{}", flags.name)); } 
    }.await;

    match result {
        Ok(result) => println!("Got result: {}", result),
        Err(e) => tracing::warn!("{:?}", anyhow::Error::from(e)),
    }       
}
```

Or this:

```
let mut N:i32 = 0;
loop{
    N += 1; 
    println!("Call number {}", N); 
    
    let hello_task = client.hello(context::current(), format!("{}", flags.name));
    let result = futures::executor::block_on(hello_task);

    match result {
        Ok(result) => println!("Got result: {}", result),
        Err(e) => tracing::warn!("{:?}", anyhow::Error::from(e)),
    }       
}
```

Then when I run the client it will send out 64 RPCs and hang on the 65th. When I debugged it, it was stuck polling in the thread pool trying to get the result back from the server. The server, on the other hand, isn't stuck at anything because it never actually received the RPC. If I terminate the client by force and start a new client, it too will send 64 RPCs and get stuck on the 65th.

It is very consistent in this behavior where I suspected it is a configuration problem. So I tried configuring it with a different configuration other than default. I replaced the config from this line:

```
let client = WorldClient::new(client::Config::default(), transport.await?).spawn();
```

That, however, did not change the behavior.

I tried looking in the documentation for tarpc but I could not find anything related to this hard limit.

What causes this behavior and is it possible to achieve more than 64 RPCs per connection?

Comment: Creating the future in `tokio::select` is very dubious - you usually want to create the request future once, then select over them in a loop, otherwise each loop iteration will create a new request only to throw it away.

Comment: Instead of select, you may want to set up a message bus here to forward results back to a single "consumer", as in MPSC.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo  I updated with the alternative code I also tried. The second portion is what I initially used, both produce same results.

Comment: @tadman updated with the original code I used, same results.

Comment: Why don't you simply `await` the task? I.e. `let result = client.hello (…).await;`

Comment: @Jmb I did that in the first part of the test, yielded same issue